# How to fix "Cannot read property 'responsive_class' of null" in Angular production build

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I made a production build of my angular app and when i try to route to another component it logs this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'responsive_class' of null
>
> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'responsive_class' of null
>     at main.872179a97a20c6d35a4f.js:1
>     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
>     at s (main.872179a97a20c6d35a4f.js:1)
>     at new t (main.872179a97a20c6d35a4f.js:1)
>     at new t (main.872179a97a20c6d35a4f.js:1)
>     at new t (main.872179a97a20c6d35a4f.js:1)
>     at y (main.872179a97a20c6d35a4f.js:1)
>     at main.872179a97a20c6d35a4f.js:1
>     at Li (main.872179a97a20c6d35a4f.js:1)
>     at Ni (main.872179a97a20c6d35a4f.js:1)
>     at D (polyfills.bd7334c8629fc0d28479.js:1)
>     at D (polyfills.bd7334c8629fc0d28479.js:1)
>     at polyfills.bd7334c8629fc0d28479.js:1
>     at e.invokeTask (polyfills.bd7334c8629fc0d28479.js:1)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (main.872179a97a20c6d35a4f.js:1)
>     at e.invokeTask (polyfills.bd7334c8629fc0d28479.js:1)
>     at t.runTask (polyfills.bd7334c8629fc0d28479.js:1)
>     at d (polyfills.bd7334c8629fc0d28479.js:1)
>     at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.bd7334c8629fc0d28479.js:1)
>     at m (polyfills.bd7334c8629fc0d28479.js:1)
> ```

When it logs this error the screen goes blank but all works fine in development build.

Anyone experienced this?

Comment: maybe , in your target component try to initialize 'responsive_class' that doesn't exist in your object !

Comment: @RoohbakhshMasoud i don't understand this, kindly explain.

Comment: please show your target  component.ts  file to help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `ng serve --aot`. It should get all the errors of an ahead-of-time build, but also with dev info like sourcemaps, which should let you pinpoint the bug.
2. Also, obviously, look up `responsive_class` in your code.

Comment: `ng serve --aot` logs the same error but i still can't find the bug.

`responsive_class` doesn't appear anywhere in my code, i've looked it up severally.

Answer (score 0):

In production configurations in angular.json, 
change buildOptimzation & optimization to false and try deploying.
It might point to the file.